# Total Probability and Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> The probability that a person has 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 or more siblings is 0.15, 0.49, 0.27, 0.06, 0.02, 0.01, respectively.

> a) Three friends who are not siblings are gathered. What is the probability that they combined have three siblings?

> b) Emma and Jacob are not siblings, but combined they have a total of 3 siblings. What is the probability that Emma has no siblings?

So for a) I have calculated that there are 7 possible ways this can occur: 1 situation where all three friends have 1 sibling, 3 cases where two friends have zero siblings and the other one has 3 siblings, and 3 cases where one person has 1 sibling, one person has 2 siblings and the last person has 0 siblings. So calculating this I obtain:

Using the notation that $P(X = N)$ means the probability that one person has $N$ siblings.

$$P(X = 1)^3 + 3*P(X = 0)^2 * P(X = 3) + 3*P(X = 2)*P(X = 1) * P(X = 0) \approx 0.181$$ Is this correct?

For part b) I used the notation $P(E = N)$ to mean the probability that Emma has N siblings, and similarly $P(J = N)$ to mean the probability that Jacob has $N$ siblings.

I interpreted the problem as asking us to calculate $$P(E = 0 | E + J = 3) = \frac{P (E = 0 \cap E + J = 3)}{P(E + J = 3)} = \frac{P(E+J = 3| E = 0) * P(E = 0)}{P(E+J = 3)} = \frac{P(J = 3)*P(E = 0)}{2*P(E = 0)*P(J = 3) + 2 * P(E = 1)*P(J = 2)} \approx 0.4416$$ where I have used Baye's rule to transform the expression.

Are my calculations correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first part of the question, when you are counting cases for $2, 1 $ and $0$ siblings, there are $3! = 6$ ways, instead of $3$. They are $\{0, 1, 2\}, \{0, 2, 1\}, \{1, 0, 2\}, \{1, 2, 0\}, \{2, 0, 1\}, \{2, 1, 0\}$. So the probability should be

$P(X = 1)^3 + 3  \ P(X = 0)^2 \  P(X = 3) + 6 \ P(X = 2) \ P(X = 1) \ P(X = 0) \approx 0.2408$

For the second one, you have written the formula correctly but the answer seems wrong.

It should be $ = \frac{0.06 \times 0.15}{2 \times 0.06 \times 0.15 + 2 \times 0.49 \times 0.27} \approx 0.0318$

Answer (score 1):

> So for a) I have calculated that there are 7 possible ways this can occur

I calculated 10 possible ways thus I did not check your calculations

- $0-0-3$
- $0-1-2$
- $0-2-1$
- $0-3-0$
- $1-0-2$
- $1-1-1$
- $1-2-0$
- $2-0-1$
- $2-1-0$
- $3-0-0$

Summing the single probabilities I get $0.240769\approx 24\%$

For (b) I get

$$\frac{0.15\times0.06}{0.15\times0.06+0.49\times0.27+0.27\times0.49+0.06\times0.15}=0.031847\approx 3\%$$